# Decompress ZIP archive in a native Windows Runtime component/application

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

This seems to be a simple task, yet my research left me with nothing: How do you extract items from a ZIP archive in a native Windows Runtime component (or application)?

Now if I were to target .NET, there's a [ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) and [ZipFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=netframework-4.8) class, that make the solution as simple as it should be. But what, if I cannot or do not want to take a dependency on the CLR?

The only compression support I was able to find in the Windows Runtime is the [Windows.Storage.Compression Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.compression), and there's really little to be had. For decompression, there *is* a [Decompressor class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.compression.decompressor), but apparently, that can only work on a single stream.

So, how do you traverse the structure of a ZIP file and extract individual items in a native Windows Runtime component?

Comment: If no API is there which seems to be the case, the only option left is to use open-source libraries like [SharpZip](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib) and modify them to work on UWP without any reference to .NET.

Comment: @meh: The fact, that there is no Windows Runtime type available does not imply, that no usable API were present (like the Windows API). Modifying a library written in C# to no longer have a dependency on the CLR amounts to rewriting hat library from scratch. The fact that it is open source does not help.

Comment: Why don't you just use Win API Compressapi.h ? MSDN  [Compression API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cmpapi/-compression-portal). You can use `COMPRESS_ALGORITHM_MSZIP` for compressor or de compressor.

Comment: @vic That solves only part of the problem. It doesn't support opening ZIP archives, querying the individual streams contained, or extracting individual streams. I guess the link you posted is just the underlying C-style API that's wrapped into the Windows Runtime types quoted in the question.