# Unzip file to a directory in UWP C++/WinRT

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I am looking for a way to extract a `*.zip` file (the whole content) to a folder. I can't find any unzip API in the Universal Windows Platform, only `ZipArchive` in C# and the [Windows.Storage.Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Compression) seems to only support single stream compress/decompress.

How can I extract a zip file in C++/WinRT?

Comment: As it stands, there's no support currently. I asked [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56314355/1889329) recently. I've started wrapping a minizip implementation in a Windows Runtime component, but it's not ready for publishing yet.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the info. This basic feature should be included in the API. Though I don't mind bundling a standard Zip library, it is troublesome to have to unzip temporarily in the app cache folder and then copy to the destination due to UWP file system access restriction.